# Zig-zag pattern in C++ using cout function, for and if-else statements

Tags: c++

While I was making a program in C++ for a zig-zag pattern I coded it as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    cout << "how many stars you want in zig zag pattern";
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            if ((i + j) % 4 == 0 && i == 1 ) { cout << "*"; }

            if (j % 2 == 0 && i == 2) { cout << "*"; }

            if ((i + j) % 4 == 0 && i == 3) { cout << "*"; }
            else { cout << " "; }
        }
    
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But using this I am not getting the desired pattern.

[The non desired pattern by the initial code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSCQr.jpg)

Please answer these:

1. What is the fault in the above code?
2. What I observed that when I put the other two if-statements in the comment line, I see that the individual statements do their respective jobs but on pairing any two and putting the third one in comment brings non-desired result.Please clear this result also.

Though I have come to know what's the right way as given below I want to know what was the fault in my initial attempt.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    cout << " how many stars you want in zig zag pattern";
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            if ((i + j) % 4 == 0 || (i == 2 && j % 4 == 0)) { cout << "*"; }
            else { cout << " "; }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[The desired pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdiGV.jpg)

I am a beginner, so I request you to use simple terms. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Well, in your own words, what do you think is the difference between the output you get and the output you want? Do you see a *pattern* in what's wrong with it? Also, what happened when you tried to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the code? In your own words, how is your code supposed to work, in detail? In your own words, when you wrote, for example, `if (((((i+j)%4)==0) && (i==1) )){ cout<< "*";}`, how did you decide that `(((((i+j)%4)==0) && (i==1) ))` was the correct thing to write, and not anything else?

Comment: In the first example, you have `if (conditionA) printStar; if (conditionB) printStar; if (conditionC) printStar; else printSpace;` This prints the space whenever `conditionC` is false, regardless of whether `conditionA` and/or `conditionB` are true. I must admit I didn't have the patience to unravel the formulas, but I suspect you are printing more spaces than you meant to. You probably meant `if (conditionA || conditionB || conditionC) printStar; else printSpace;`, or equivalently `if (conditionA) printStar; else if (conditionB) printStar; else if (conditionC) printStar; else printSpace;`

Comment: While debugging I observed that the output I got had only the third if statement working properly but the other two's output seemed shifted towards right. I programmed to make the loop works till n ( for n=9 I gave the output) but I found that the first two if statements have taken the column number more than 9. I don't understand why the asterisks were shifted? Also I saw the pattern in the asterisks coordinates, which showed that the pattern has * when the row (i) is first plus also satisfies the condition that sum of the row and column number is divisible by 4 and so for the third one.

Comment: Holy parentheses, Batman!!!

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you so much, I just found that by using else if statements it gives the right pattern. Can you please clarify what does the program perceives for the first row when I use the initial code without else if as I found that in the output the first row had 2 asterisks in the coordinates (1,3) (which is correct) and (1,8) instead of (1,7) where their sum is divisible by 4.

Comment: Without `else`, you sometimes print a star followed by a space, rather than a star alone, in a single iteration of the loop. In other words, you may be printing more than `n` characters on each row.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Once again, thank you for help, I got it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You program is printing extra spaces because of the way you have wrote the `if` statements. Look at these statements:

```
        if (((((i+j)%4)==0) && (i==1) )){ cout<< "*";}
        if ((( j%2)==0) && ( i==2 )) { cout<< "*";}
        if ( ((i+j)%4==0) && (i==3)) { cout << "*";}
        else { cout<< " ";}
```

note that every iteration will check all the `3` `if` conditions and space character will be printed every time except when the third `if` condition results in `true`, irrespective of first and second `if` condition results (`true` or `false`), and this is the cause of problem that you are noticing in your program output.

Lets dry run the inner `for` loop for value `i = 1`:

Iteration I :  `j = 1`

```
First if condition:
i+j = 1+1 = 2
2 % 4 != 0  
result: false,
Second if condition ultimately result in false because of '&& ( i==2 )', and
Third if condition ultimately result in false because of '&& (i==3)', so a 
space character will be printed
```

Iteration II:  `j = 2`

```
First if condition:
i+j = 1+2 = 3
3 % 4 != 0  
result: false,
Second if condition ultimately result in false because of '&& ( i==2 )', and
Third if condition ultimately result in false because of '&& (i==3)', so a 
space character will be printed
```

Iteration III:  `j = 3`

```
First if condition:
i+j = 1+3 = 4
4 % 4 != 0  
result: true, '*' will be printed
Second if condition ultimately result in false because of '&& ( i==2 )', and
Third if condition ultimately result in false because of '&& (i==3)', so a 
space character will be printed
```

Here you can see that the third `if` condition resulting in `false` and the `else` part of this `if` will be executed **which will print the undesired space character** after the `'*'` character printed by from `if` block. Thats why you are getting the extra spaces in your output. Change the `if` conditions to this:

```
        if (((((i+j)%4)==0) && (i==1) )) { cout<< "*";}
        else if ((( j%2)==0) && ( i==2 )) { cout<< "*";}
        else if ( ((i+j)%4==0) && (i==3)) { cout << "*";}
        else { cout<< " ";}
```

Note the `else` in above code, the space should only printed when all the 3 `if` condition result in `false` and if any of the `if` condition result in `true` only a `'*'` should be printed. With this your program will output as expected.